# Laravel Nova Resource Tool on Index View

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I can add a custom resource tool to the detail view of a resource.

The Laravel Nova Docs say:

> ... resource tools are displayed on a particular resource's detail
> screen

How can I add the resource tool to the index view of a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource tools are specifically for a single resource..

If you want to display a custom component above the resource index.. [Create a custom card](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/cards.html#defining-cards)

If you want the entire page without the resource table below it..  [Create a custom tool](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/tools.html#defining-tools)

You can also package tools, resource tools and cards  in the same  package and share assets.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Hi, I want to add a new icon beside the view icon on the Nova.. Any idea how i can do this?]

I want to add a new icon beside the view icon on the Nova. Any idea how I can do this?